# Get list of Site.com languages (other attributes) in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura, site.com

Does anyone know if it is possible to access list of languages available for the community site?

I need to add language switcher component and wondered if it was possible without passing the languages as a parameter to the component.

Also is there a way how to get other parameters of the site in lightning components?